# Should services be used in a ViewModel

Tags: c#, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, dependency-injection, services

So I have a service which is injected in my controller via dependency injection. I can either use it in the controller multiple times to convert a value when assigning to a particular property in a ViewModel. Or I could pass an instance of the service to the ViewModel in the constructor and use it in the the setter of the property (C#). Which would be the best way?

I feel like the setter way would be the most maintainable. However, I don't want to pollute the ViweModel. I'm not sure if I am breaking any best practices here.

Comment: When I see a line `viemodel.Name = "raw name"` - it would be a big surprise if `Name` will contain something different. And definitely I wouldn't expect that settings value to the property will call some possibly "heavy" service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I have a service which is injected in my controller via dependency injection

As described, this sounds an odd thing to do. The Controller should have access to a Model, ideally via injection as you are doing. That Model might use a service, but the Controller shouldn't be accessing a service directly.

The Controller calls some aspect of the Model, `SomeModel.DoSomething()`. Then it will query the Model to get it's current state, constructing a simple value object, ViewModel, which it then passes to the View.

Of course, I'm reading a lot into just one sentence. It's quite possible that this "service" is your model.

> I feel like the setter way would be the most maintainable. However, I don't want to pollute the ViweModel. I'm not sure if I am breaking any best practices here.

The sole purpose of the ViewModel is to just expose the data needed to the View. How it does that is really just an implementation detail. As long as it only exposes the data needed via publicly read-only properties, it fits the brief of a ViewModel. If the easiest way to do that is to inject the Model (or service in your case) into it and let it process that to obtain the data, then I personally see no problem with that.

Comment: The service injection makes more sense in MVC, where models are generally reduced to DTO-style objects without their own retrieval logic. It's possible OP has carried this inject-into-controller habit over from MVC. You're right that it's odd to do so in MVVM, I just wanted to point out why it may have been the case.

Comment: DTO or Domain Model, I don't think Models should be responsible for retrieving themselves. Model should be persistence Ignorant. And therefore injection Services in View Model, and Loading Model during construction from services will make more sense.